# Rails 3, how can I validate an emails domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

The domain name is static so it will always be the same.  Its not like a magic number that could so I need to right a regex or use something in rails that can validate that domain = "domain.com" or whatever I put there...

I have been playing with:

```
 validates_each :email |record, attr, value|
      record.errors.add attr 'bad domain' unless /ravennainteractive.com$/ =~ value
  end
```

that doesn't work...

thanks so much for your help.

### Edit 1/9/12

So after looking closer at the rails guides, I modified what I had with what Vivek said and here is what I am using:

```
validates_each :email do |record, attr, value|
       record.errors.add(attr, 'You must use an ravennainteractive.com email address') unless value =~ /ravennainteractive.com$/
   end
```

this is accepting invalid values: (from the log) "approvals_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"tj@4thavenuemedia.com"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}

I should also note that this is validating on a nested form.  This is a Recommendation#new form with a fields_for...

any other ideas?

Comment: MU, thanks for the note on the missing do... I am sorry for the lack of clarity.  by doesn't work, it was accepting invalid values.  However, after putting the do in there, the view renders but it still accepts invalid values... I am editing the original post with additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it this helps, but shouldn't the value match the expression?

Shouldn't it be `unless value =~ /ravennainteractive.com$/` ?

Comment: Despite using the same `=~` operator, Ruby is backwards from Perl on this feature.

Comment: @Greg: Ruby has both `Regexp =~ String` and `String =~ Regexp` and they both produce the same result for a simple test like this.

Comment: Ah, I see. They're different, but not different in a way that matters here.